# C++ what’s the proper way to handle temporary object and array

Tags: c++

Recently I read a lot about sort algorithm, and I found the strange which made me feel confused.
In the function, it needs to create a temporary array in the for loop.
And the sample code is

```
for(;;)//ignore the condition
{
    int *b = new int[N];
    //some code
    delete b[];
}
```

The question is : Why not just create it directly without new operator, for the compiler will destroy it automatically and release the memory after each iteration. Like write this in the loop

```
int b[N];
```

And in the previous, I always use this method to create the temporary type/object. Am I totally wrong or something like array is different from built in type?

So, kind Stack Overflowers, can anyone give me some advice?

Comment: Assuming N is not a constant, you can’t. But you definitely should use std::vector instead of pointer and new.

Comment: Just a little heads up: GCC will happily accept this if N is not known at compile time, since it supports VLAs (variable-length arrays), however, many compilers do not (like MSVC). You should use a vector for this, like the other suggestions, unless you aren't worried about portability. You can technically get VLA-like support using `alloca()`, but you **really** shouldn't do this.

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh *GCC will happily accept this if N is not known at compile time,* -- IMO, it really shouldn't happily accept it, unless the programmer requests it via command-line.  I don't understand why gcc and other compilers make VLA's the default.  It makes new programmers believe they're writing valid C++ code.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: Indeed. I always wonder why GCC gets away with awful default settings like that while MSVC is criticised for them. Seems unfair. Every C++ compiler should be in strict standards mode unless told otherwise.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie It shouldn't but it does. It's important to know though that it's a C99 extension, and an intended feature, and not a hack though, even if it is not standard C++.

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh -- Well, VLA's may not even work in situations where "regular" arrays do work .  I don't know if gcc addressed this yet, but VLA's cannot be used in STL algorithm functions, even though normal arrays can be used.   I remember seeing weird compiler errors when using VLA's in place of regular arrays in things like `std::find`, `std::sort`, etc.  This puts VLA's as more of a hack (IMO) with respect to C++.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I've never had an issue when using VLAs with pointers for the `<algorithm>` utilities, since pointers are effectively random-access iterators. I'm not sure what kind of issues you're having with them, because you should have the size and a pointer to the first element, which allows you to use them like any pointer iterator. It's obviously not best practice, but if you're only targeting one platform and need the added convenience, why not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why not just create it directly without new operator, for the compiler
>   will destroy it automatically and release the memory after each
>   iteration.

Indeed, why not?

If `N` is known at compile time, then go on and use `int b[N]`.

If `N` is not known at compile time, then `std::vector<int>` should be used instead:

```
for(;;)//ignore the condition
{
    std::vector<int> b(N);
    //some code
}
```

You should ask the author of the code why he or she uses `new[]` and `delete[]`, but chances are it's simply lack of experience.

Comment: It is important to note that some compilers allow `int b[N]` even if `N` is not known at compile time. But this is a non standard extension and not standard c++

Comment: Actually the compilers do not allow it if the appropriate compiler flags are used.  That is one of my complaints with those compilers -- they should **not** allow it by default.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Solved my problem. The code is from visualgo.net and I guess that STL is not recommended in the process of sort algotirhm learning.

Comment: @balki: But if I did that, I'd have to explain all the time that some compilers allow binding temporaries to non-const references when I explain temporary objects, or that some compilers allow `void main`. I don't want to give the false impression that GCC's default behaviour is normal or good.

Comment: @ShawnXu: It's the standard library, not the "STL", but that's a nitpick. More importantly, I think that learning algorithms and learning C++ containers are independent topics. The first is computer science, the second is software engineering.

Comment: VLAs (variable-length arrays) are not a hack, it's a non-portable extension based on the C99 standard. GCC supports C99, MSVC does not, and C++ only requires C89. You should not rely on VLAs if you need any portability. `vector` is the appropriate, cross-platform way to do this.

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh: Whether VLAs are a hack or not, or if they are legal C or not, is not the issue here. They are not C++.

Comment: @ChristianHackl they're not, but it's what we could call a fairly convenient extension present in one of the most popular compilers. If you only ever target that compiler, and document when you use extensions specific to that compiler, I don't see a major issue... If you aim for any portability, however....

Comment: One more question: whether they are the same behavior ?1.new a array and delete it manually 2.let the compiler do that like I said .They can be viewed equally?

Comment: @ShawnXu: Behind the scenes, different things happen in all three cases, both in abstract terms of the language definition and (likely) in an implementation. However, that doesn't matter much, as long as you don't use `new[]`. It'd be helpful to know what exactly you are asking about...

Answer (score 3):

If `N` is known at compile means, using

```
int b[N];
```

is fine. If you are able to use a C++11 compiler use of `std::array` is another option.

```
std::array<int, N> b;
```

If `N` is not known at compile time, use of

```
int b[N];
```

is non-standard. It is supported only by some compilers as an extension.

If you don't know the size at compile time, use `std::vector` instead of managing dynamically allocated memory in application code. There is no sensible reason for not using `std::vector`.

```
for(;;)//ignore the condition
{
    std::vector<int> b(N);
    //some code

    // No need for this at all.
    // delete b[];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Why not just create it directly without new operator, for the compiler
>   will destroy it automatically and release the memory after each
>   iteration.

Depending on the size of your stack and the size of the temporary array, you may want to create the array using dynamic memory so that you don't blow your stack (run out of stack memory).

Of course, a vector is a better option than the array as it has already been mentioned.

Comment: Good point about the stack size if `N` is big, I completely forgot to mention that in my answer. +1 from me.